# Wrapping a div within an <a> attribute

Tags: html

I am wandering what the general rule of doing the above is, my editor still gives me a warning saying that the div is in an `invalid location`. Most questions regarding this are pushing on for 6 years old. Is it still bad to wrap a `div` element with an `<a>` attribute? for example, is the following code an acceptable thing to do now or should it be avoided?

```
<a href="/somelink.html">
  <div class="fancyBox">
    <p> some content </p>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: there's nothing wrong in fact it is applied in my cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your editor is out of date.

As of HTML 5 (published as a W3C recommendation on 28 October 2014), `<div>` elements are allowed as child elements of `<a>` elements.

This wasn't the case in HTML 4.